# Can I replace the column value while selecting and then use it for comparison with a column value from another table?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Basically, I want to compare two columns of two different (let's call them source and destination) tables but while selecting from first table, I want to replace the value to something else because source table might have some garbage value which should be sanitised (replaced with a valid value based on some conditions) before I actually compare it with the second table. For example,

Table 1

```
First_Name: "Aman"
Roll_Number: "00000"

First_Name: "Raju"
Roll_Number: "13456"
```

Table 2

```
Name: "Aman"
Roll_Number: "11223"

Name: "Raju"
Roll_Number: "13456"
```

I tried using this query:

```
select t1.First_Name, t1.Roll_Number, t2.Name, t2.Roll_Number, 
        CASE WHEN (t1. Roll_Number is Null or t1.Roll_Number = ' ' 
                    or t1.Roll_Number = '' or t1.PARTNER_ID = '00000') 
            THEN '11223' 
            ELSE t1.Roll_Number 
        END AS ROLL_NUM_TO_BE_COMPARED 
from SOURCE_STUDENT t1, DESTINATION_STUDENT t2 
where t1.First_Name = t2.Name 
and (t1.Roll_Number != t2.Roll_Number OR t2.Roll_Number != ROLL_NUM_TO_BE_COMPARED);
```

Context:
Data is getting migrated from source table to destination table by some service. There should be a script which compares the data (source vs destination). Migration logic already considers "00000" as "11223" and hence the comparison logic should also consider the same. Instead of updating the source, I want to just replace garbage with "11223" and then compare it with destination to get the real mismatched values.

Comment: I woudl start by using a JOIN and not a `from SOURCE_STUDENT t1, DESTINATION_STUDENT t2 `

Comment: There is no primary key/foreign key relationship between the two tables @RiggsFolly

Comment: Whats this then? `t1.First_Name = t2.Name `

Comment: That's column First_Name of table 1 getting compared with column Name in table 2. Source and destination have different column names but values are equal.

Comment: So there is your JOIN. `from SOURCE_STUDENT t1 JOIN DESTINATION_STUDENT t2 ON t1.First_Name = t2.Name`